# Why is this throwing a KeyError when it has a value?

Tags: python, string-formatting, keyerror

I've stepped through this and checked every value with pdb trace but can't figure out why I'm getting a KeyError, everything has its expected value. This is the function:

```
def get_formatted_timestamp(date_field, time_field):
    # expects date_field = yyyy-M-d
    # expects time_field = H:m:s
    # outputs yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:SSSZ ('T' and 'Z' are literals)
    dt = date_field.strip().split('/')
    tm = time_field.strip().split(':')
    if len(dt) != 3 or len(tm) != 3 or len(dt[0]) != 4:
        print 'invalid date or time: {} {}'.format(date_field, time_field)
        return '1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'  # error date value
    y = dt[0]
    M = dt[1] if len(dt[1]) == 2 else '0'+dt[1]
    d = dt[2] if len(dt[2]) == 2 else '0'+dt[2]
    H = tm[0] if len(tm[0]) == 2 else '0'+tm[0]
    m = tm[1] if len(tm[1]) == 2 else '0'+tm[1]
    s = tm[2] if len(tm[2]) == 2 else '0'+tm[2]
    return '{y}-{M}-{d}T{H}:{m}:{s}.000Z'.format(y, M, d, H, m, s)  # KeyError
```

The error is:

```
KeyError: 'y'
```

However, `y` has a proper year string value (I checked `repr(y)`; it is a string as expected). I also checked that `dt[0]` was valid, and it is showing a proper year value.

Why is it throwing a KeyError when everything has an expected value? I'm stumped.

Here is the pdb output where I checked every value manually:

```
(Pdb) print repr(dt[0])
'2014'
(Pdb) print repr(y)
'2014'
(Pdb) print repr(M)
'02'
(Pdb) print repr(d)
'10'
(Pdb) print repr(H)
'15'
(Pdb) print repr(m)
'35'
(Pdb) print repr(s)
'19'
```

Comment: Note that you could just type `dt[0]` at the debugger prompt and PDB will already use `print repr(..)` for that value. For `d` and `s`, use `!d` and `!s`, respectively, to avoid these being seen as a debugger command. I always prefix my variable introspections with `!` for that reason.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't know that -- thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't *have* a key `y`, because you don't have any keyword arguments. You only have *positional arguments*. That's not the same thing; even if you used a variable with that name doesn't mean that it is also a keyword argument.

Either use digits to pull out positional arguments, or use actual keyword arguments. If all your local variables match the slot names, you can use `locals()` to provide those keyword arguments:

```
return '{y}-{M}-{d}T{H}:{m}:{s}.000Z'.format(**locals())
```

but otherwise you'd have to give each name used in the format an actual keyword:

```
return '{y}-{M}-{d}T{H}:{m}:{s}.000Z'.format(y=y, M=M, d=d, H=H, m=m, s=s)
```

Note that your code appears to reinvent the date-parsing and date-formatting wheels. The following would do the same thing but also validate that you have a valid date (e.g. no February 29th outside of a leap year, etc.):

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_formatted_timestamp(date_field, time_field):
    # expects date_field = yyyy-M-d
    # expects time_field = H:m:s
    # outputs yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z ('T' and 'Z' are literals)
    try:
        dt = datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(date_field, time_field), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    except ValueError:
        return '1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'  # error date value
    return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
```

Comment: D'oh! I should have realized that. Thanks! I'll mark this as accepted in a few minutes when it lets me.

Comment: Also, it's so confusing when date/time APIs use conflicting symbols. Joda uses the opposite as Python for `M` and `m`, and `S` is milliseconds rather than seconds.

Comment: Python follows the C [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) and [strptime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) functions here; I'm afraid it is Joda that is deviating.